# Can pointers generate distinct results in different compilers? What's the problem?

Tags: c, pointers, towers-of-hanoi

I'm studying with a bit more depth access to memory in C and I have a question I can not solve. I have the code below, which solve the Towers of Hanoi iteratively. And it works great on both GCC and CLANG, but not on VS2017.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void solve(const int NUM_DISK)
{
    const int ALPHA[2][3][2] =
    {
        { { 1, 3 }, { 3, 2 }, { 2, 1 } },   /* even */
        { { 1, 2 }, { 2, 3 }, { 3, 1 } }    /* odd */
    };

    const int MAX_ITER = 1 << NUM_DISK;

    int **list = (int **) malloc( (MAX_ITER - 1) * sizeof(int*) );

    int start, gap, disk, k, rank;

    for (start = 1, gap = 2, disk = 1; disk <= NUM_DISK; ++disk, start <<= 1, gap <<= 1)
    {
        int **pp = (int **) &ALPHA[(NUM_DISK + disk) % 2];

        for (k = 0, rank = start; rank < MAX_ITER + (disk % 2); rank += gap, ++k)
        {
            list[rank - 1] = (int *) &pp[k % 3];
        }
    }

    for (rank = 0; rank < (MAX_ITER - 1); ++rank)
    {
        char origem  = list[rank][0] + 64;
        char destino = list[rank][1] + 64;
        printf("%4d ) %c --> %c\n", (rank + 1), origem, destino);
    }

    free(list);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int d = atoi(argv[1]);
    solve(d);
    return 0;
}
```

Assuming we have 3 disks, the results are as follows:

```
RESULT IN GCC        RESULT IN VS2017

1 ) A --> C          1 ) A --> C
2 ) A --> B          2 ) A --> B
3 ) C --> B          3 ) C --> C
4 ) A --> C          4 ) A --> C
5 ) B --> A          5 ) C --> B
6 ) B --> C          6 ) B --> B
7 ) A --> C          7 ) A --> C
```

Please, can someone tell me what's the problem?

Comment: Rule of Thumb: If the same code produces different output on different compilers you are very likely to have *undefined behavior* in your code

Comment: This code is not very readable. To answer the title - yes, if i contains Undefined behavior, or is relying on implementation defined behavior.

Comment: @UnholySheep, I figured I had something to do with it, but I can not visualize it. Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: @EugeneSh., Please suggest me so you can improve readability. I'm very grateful.

Comment: Remove unneeded casts (`malloc` result and some others), simplify the `for` construct (number of initializations, operations and comparisons in the `for(...)`). And add some comments.

Comment: `pp` is declared as an `int **`, which is a pointer to a pointer to an `int`, but is assigned the value of `&ALPHA[(NUM_DISK + disk) % 2]`, which is a pointer to an array of 3 arrays of 2 `const int`. The forced cast `(int **)` masks this error — **Do not use casts in C to force pointer conversion.** (It is two errors, actually: A pointer to an array is not a pointer to a pointer, and `ALPHA` ultimately contains `const int`, but `pp` is missing `const`.)

Comment: confirmed wrong results using `gcc` on my machine (i.e. same as VS above) as well. i.e. undefined behavior in code mentioned by @UnholySheep

Comment: The assignment of `&pp[k % 3]` to `list[rank - 1]` is similarly wrong.

Comment: @static_cast, I got the same result here: [cpp.sh/5ol45](cpp.sh/5ol45). Thanks.

Comment: @EugeneSh., Thank you. I'll do it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil,I believe you have pointed out all the paths that I must evaluate. I will try to make all the corrections you have shown. I am very grateful for your help.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I was really lost in this code :-)

Comment: the posted code causes the compiler to output several warning messages about type conversions.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results )